# How I append specific columns from various excels and all of their sheets using pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, append

I have a lot of excels with a lot of sheets(with various names each one) and various columns in them.

Every sheet of every excel has three columns that I want to extract (Name, Title, Database) and place them in one file with only one sheet. So, the output file should have three columns consisted from all the other excels' and sheets' columns Name, Title, Database data.

Trying to do so with the following code, grabs data only from every first sheet.

By adding the `sheet_name=None` in `read_excel()`, I see: `TypeError: Can only append a Series if ignore_index=True or if the Series has a name.`

By adding `ignore_index=True` in `append()`, the output file has no data in it.

Thanks for your time! I'm a beginner in programming.

```
import pandas as pd

#Setting SourceFiles
my_files = [(r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\a.xls'),
            (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\b.xls'),
            (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\c.xls'),
            (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\d.xls'),
            (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\e.xls'),
            (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\f.xls'),
            (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\g.xls'),
            (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\h.xls'),
            (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\i.xls'),
            (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\j.xls'),
            (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\k.xls'),
            (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\l.xls'),
            (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\m.xls'),
            (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\n.xls'),
            (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\o.xls'),
            (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\p.xls'),
            (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\q.xls'),
            (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\r.xls'),
            (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\s.xls'),
            (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\t.xls'),
            (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\u.xls'),
            (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\v.xls'),
            (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\w,y,z.xls')]

#Combining the SourceFiles
df = pd.DataFrame()

for f in my_files:
    data = pd.read_excel(f) #Here I set the sheet_name=None
    df = df.append(data)    #Here I set the ignore_index=True

#Defining the columns I want from the Source file and how I want them (Sorted and with Dropped duplicates)

columns_i_want = (pd.DataFrame(df, columns= ['Name', 'Title', 'Database']))
sorted_data = column_i_want.sort_values('Name', ascending=True)

#Transfering the data to an other excel
column_i_want.to_excel (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\output.xlsx', index = False, header=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found how to do it! I don't think that it's the best or the easiest way, but it works for me:

```
import pandas as pd

test = [(r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\a.xls'),
        (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\b.xls'),
        (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\c.xls'),
        (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\d.xls'),
        (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\e.xls'),
        (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\f.xls'),
        (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\g.xls'),
        (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\h.xls'),
        (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\i.xls'),
        (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\j.xls'),
        (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\k.xls'),
        (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\l.xls'),
        (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\m.xls'),
        (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\n.xls'),
        (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\o.xls'),
        (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\p.xls'),
        (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\q.xls'),
        (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\r.xls'),
        (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\s.xls'),
        (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\t.xls'),
        (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\u.xls'),
        (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\v.xls'),
        (r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\REAL\w,y,z.xls')]

df = pd.DataFrame()

def merge(data):
    df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel(data, sheet_name=None), ignore_index=True)
    df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns= ['Name', 'Title', 'Database'])
    column_i_want = (pd.DataFrame(df).drop_duplicates(subset=["Title"]))
    sorted_data = (column_i_want.sort_values(['Name', 'Title'], ascending=True))
    return sorted_data

for i in test:
    x = merge(i)
    df = df.append(x)

df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\John\Dev\Mini_Personal_scripts\The_Excel_Project\Excels\output.xlsx', index = False, header=True)
```